# Sweet & simple source code editor

Tags: editor

Can you advise a simple light source code editor for Windows and Mac?

I do not want it to have to take the whole project the file came from into context or provide any project management or integrated debugging features. I just want to take a quick but informative view at a single source code file with some syntax highlighting and i am sick of having to wait for VS or Xcode to start every time. For example, under Linux i would use Kate or Vim so something similar is preferred.

Comment: I'm sure you could make ed(1) work on Windows and MacOS :-)

Comment: @Stephen C ed(1) unfortunately has no syntax highlight :-) But it's damn fast

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Mac, use vim.

For windows, I use [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) or [textpad](http://www.textpad.com/)

Comment: +1, Notepad++ is really versatile and supports a variety of different languages.

Answer (score 2):

[Vim for Windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc)? (For Mac, of course, you should already *have* Vim.)

Comment: If you're used to VIM, why switch, so +1

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, I'd recommend [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). [E](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) is a Windows equivalent.

Comment: TextMate is what I use. It's nice because it's simple when you need it to be and power-packed when you need it to be. I can call `mate config.py` to edit a single file or `mate .` for an entire directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)? I use it for perl development on OS X. And win32 Vim build on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Also for windows, I would recommend [ConTEXT](http://www.contexteditor.org/).
It's free, simple, lightweight, and you can plug-in many different highlighters for different languages. You can even make your own, or tune existing ones.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) is what I use for this. Ideal for quick peek in source files, I also use it from time to time to make quick changes without opening a full-blown IDE.

It's a lightweight notepad replacement with syntax highlighting (based on scintilla, the same component as Notepad++).

Answer (score 0):

Mac: TextWrangler
Win: Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

GVIM is also an option. it has a few options that suit a mouse environment over regular vim.

SCITE is excellent for the windows environment, but I have not used it in a mac environment.

Answer (score 0):

BBEdit for Mac.  TextWrangler is a free subset of BBEdit.